# File Processing- create new file with additional information

Tags: java, file, file-processing

I have a file and inside it has some tables and my question is how can I create a new file but in this file it includes both tables and additional information. I tried in terminal but I could not find it, help me please...

Comment: This isn't even close to enough information to begin to help you. Please elaborate. how can a file have tables? is it HTML? CSV? something else? Define exactly what you have and what you're trying to do

Comment: in java I made a code that shows the table of student id and quizzes in "scores.txt" but in the next  text called "finalReport.txt" I want to add averages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you want to check when to create a new file, when is the next text called ?

How about to use JFileChooser, just choose or create a new file ?

Maybe something like this:

```
private void createNewFile() {
 File newFile;
 File nf = null;
 String nt = "someName";
 if((newFile = new File(DirectoryPath.toString())).exists()) { //it must be a directorypath to create a new file in it.
  nf = new File(DirectoryPath, "withAverage" + nt + ".txt"); //create a new file
  nf.createNewFile();
 } averageFile = nf;
}

private void fileWriterInput() { 
 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(averageFile); 
 try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
  bw.newLine();
  bw.append(inputString);
  bw.append("----------------------------------");
  bw.flush();
 }
}
```

Comment: I mean I have some code that calculates averages.... and I create a file like a.writeData("scores.txt") but in the new file I want to create, "finalReport.txt", this file shows me the averages and scores.txt just should show me the quizzes

Comment: Files may have content/data, but each file should have it's own existence. Or you mean you want to merge it or to copy content from one file to the other file ? Maybe you mean to start a new filewriter stream to create a new file.